# Question recommendation feature

Tags: feature-request

Is there a feature on any of the stack exchange sites that will recommend questions based on your skill set?  Either something where you can select from a list of skills, or have the system learn automatically based on previous answers (similar to a Netflix style recommendation system)?

Comment: Oh, Netflix now? Well, at least it's not Facebook.

Comment: That's basically what Stack Overlfow's "Interesting" tab tries to do

Comment: Oh, there's the My Tags tab of the Unanswered tab too (not sure that's an answer since this is a feature request).

Answer (score 1):

And how will that be implemented? The server is a computer, it can't really compare question type.

Frequented tags are already highlighted on the main page(if you don't have any favorited tags). I think that's as far as it goes.

Netflix's system works on how well your ratings for various movies match up with others. Unfortunately, out "rating" system (votes) is not for "I'm able to answer this question", but it's for "this is a good question".

Of course, we can compare the question with other people who answer questions similar to you. But how will that work for new questions? These people will already have to have *answered the question* for it to be recommended to you. The chance that you will be able to provide an answer decreases if there already are answers--new answers are supposed to be better than the pre-existing ones.

So, while I would like a feature like this, I'm at a loss at how this feature will actually choose questions to recommend.

Comment: Well for this to work it would require a bit more work from the user asking the question -- right now you can enter from 1 to 5 general tags, but to make something like this work you would have to have sub categories for each major tag.  Some of this may be semi-automated by picking up keywords from the question and suggesting tags (similar to how it suggest other similar questions).  Or add the ability for others to classify questions if they don't have a direct answer.

Comment: @Derek the classification of the question via tags(even subtags) will not help. Recommended questions should be ones that are _good quality_ and within your expertise. Since we don't have (and will never have) "beginner/intermediate/expert" tags, this won't work really well.