# Recommendation model on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion

I am trying to understand how Stack Overflow recommends **questions** to the users. Until now, my observation is *tags* of recommended questions are associated with *tags* user is related to (tags of questions/answers he posted and likes). However, what might be the underlying model of question recommendation on Stack Overflow?

And what might be an appropriate model for the general question recommendation problem?

Comment: This is not how SO does it, but here is an example of using tags, questions and answers from SO in a recommender: http://myrrix.com/example-stackoverflow-and-computation-layer/

Comment: Are you talking about the "interesting" tab on the homepage, or the hot questions, or what?

Comment: Related  [Question recommendation feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132899/289691)